# In which file directory are the desktop background wallpapers kept?

Tags: 14.04, desktop-background

I'm just here to ask which file directory I can find my desktop background wallpapers in 14.04 so I can copy them onto a USB and take them over to my Windows 8 PC so I can use them there.

Comment: @Web-E too quick.

Comment: Too right! Sorry I didn't see this question, please feel free to close my question.